# how to catch an exception and convert into another by using ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler

I have a spring application created with maven, it has the typical flow:

```
controller -> service -> external gateway
```

When querying the external gateway from service, it can return a FeingException, and I want to capture and convert into a custom one:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GatewayErrorHandling {

   @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
   public MyCustomException handleFeignException(FeignException e) {;

       return  new  MyCustomException("test");
   }
 }
```

Then I try to catch it into another handler but it doesnt work

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ServiceErrorHandling {

   @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
   public void handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException e) {;

       System.out.println("exception catched");
   }
 }
```

I dont know what point I am missing to not be able to reach this system.out.println line

Update: after Dirk Deyne comment, the first method is:

```
   @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
   public void handleFeignException(FeignException e) {;

       throw new  MyCustomException("test");
   }
```

with same result

Comment: `throw new  MyCustomException("test")` instead of returning it

Comment: umm I'm having same result, the other exceptionHandler is not catching it

Comment: On the other hand, if I correctly understand what you are trying to do, chained exception handlers do not work. Per request only one handler can be invoked.

Comment: Is it because you want to return a similar response(only a few changes based on exception) for both exceptions?

Comment: Also, you can put multiple `@ExceptionHandler` methods in the same handler class, for the different Exception classes.